# Android Eclipse: for each line of EditText

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext, lines

I want to know how I can get the count of lines of an EditText and then set a line to a string.

Something like that:

```
String current_line;

for (int i = 0; i < EditText1.LinesLength; ++i) {
       current_line = EditText1.Lines(i);
}
```

I can't make this work..

Comment: Ok, I found an answer how to count the lines. But I still don't know how to set the current_line to the current line..

something like that: current_line = EditText1.Lines(i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the edittext lines like this..

Try using `String.split()`. Code example:

```
String multiLines = streetEt.getText().toString();
String[] streets;
String delimiter = "\n";

streets = multiLines.split(delimiter);
```

Now you have an array of streets.

Let's say, for example, your `EditText` reads `"1st St.\nHighway Rd.\nUniversity Ave."` (or is those 3 streets separated by line breaks, instead of you actually seeing \n). Following the code example I provided you,

```
multiLines becomes "1st St.\nHighway Rd.\nUniversity Ave."

`streets = multiLines.split(delimiter);` fills the array streets with the street names, i.e.


    streets[0] = "1st St."
    streets[1] = "Highway Rd."
    streets[2] = "University Ave."
```